# TinyMCE valid_children not working as expected

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

We're trying to add a custom style format to TinyMCE which acts as a wrapper but don't want it to appear inside another DIV, table cell or list.

We thought that we could achieve this with the `valid_children` option but it is being ignored.

Here is a test configuration;

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
width: '100%',
height: 600,
 plugins: [
  'advlist autolink link lists anchor',
  'visualblocks visualchars code',
  'table paste'
],
style_formats: [
        {'title': 'Test', 'block': 'div', 'wrapper': true, 'block_expand': true, 'deep': true, 'classes': 'test', 'remove': 'all'}
  ],
  valid_children: '-div[div], -li[div], -ul[div], -ol[div], -td[div], -th[div]',
});
```

And here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4ymo893/

If you make a selection that contains part of a list or table then the wrapper is applied inside each list/cell which breaks the rules we set in `valid_children`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I pasted valid_children twice. See updated link... still doesn't work;

[https://jsfiddle.net/r4ymo893/](https://jsfiddle.net/r4ymo893/)

Comment: Hi @user2026237 did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem and it's really annoying as I'd like to be able to add top-level wrappers for styling blocks of content.

Answer (score 0):

I think its cause you have `valid_children` twice.  Need to update to this:

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    width: '100%',
    height: 600,
     plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link lists anchor',
      'visualblocks visualchars code',
      'table paste'
    ],
    style_formats: [
            {'title': 'Test', 'block': 'div', 'wrapper': true, 'block_expand': true, 'deep': true, 'classes': 'test', 'remove': 'all'}
      ],
      valid_children: '+body[style], -div[div], -li[div], -ul[div], -ol[div], -td[div], -th[div]',
  });
```

Comment: Hi @mikerojas, that was my mistake - I corrected the question and updated the fiddle. It still doesn't work.